# Remove HTML using PHP (ob_start + dom parser)

Tags: php, html, ob-start, domparser

I need to learn how to remove html tags using PHP.

This is what I have in mind (I think DOM phrasing is what I need but I cant figure out how it works. A working example would be a big help for me. I can't install any external library’s and I am running PHP 5):

```
function the_remove_function($remove){

//  dom parser code here?

return $remove;}

// return all content into a string
ob_start('the_remove_function');
```

**Example code:**

```
<body>
<div class="a"></div>
<div id="b"><p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p></div>
<div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

**Questions:**

**1) How do I return:**

```
<body>
<p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p>
</body>
```

**2) How do I return:**

```
<body>
<div class="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

**3) How do I return:**

```
<body>
<div class="a"></div>
<p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p>
<div id="d"></div>
</body>
```

**Next example code:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='test-css'  href='http://www.domain.com/css/test.css?ver=2011' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.domain.com/js/test.js?ver=2010123'></script>
</head>
```

**4) How do I return:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='test-css'  href='http://www.domain.com/css/test.css?ver=2011' type='text/css' media='all' />
</head>
```

**5) How do I return:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.domain.com/js/test.js?ver=2010123'></script>
</head>
```

Thanks for reading :)

Comment: why not just use the strip_tags() method?

Comment: Thanks for comment. Can you give an example for question 1?

Comment: looks like he's got some special cases to remove in-between and stuff

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you had specific parts in mind. You'd need DOM parsing. But that alone won't work. So you'd have to parse the bits you need (e.g. the P tag) and add the rest programmaticaly.

Comment: I now understands what I have to do. Thanks JohanP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use all the DOM classes of PHP, you will the doc here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and I'm sur you can find a lot of tutorial in you prefer.

Here is an exemple for your second case :

```
<?php
$content = '<body><div class="a"></div><div id="b"><p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p></div><div id="d"></div></body>';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($content);

//Get your p element
$p = $doc->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
//Remove the p tag from the DOM
$p->parentNode->removeChild($p);

//Save you new DOM tree
$html = $doc->saveXML();

echo $html;
//If you want to delete the first line
echo substr($html, strpos($html, "\n"));
```

Comment: Would you like to give me an example? I think this is complicated to learn.

Comment: I updated my post. If you want more details search on SO there plenty other examples.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) library. It does exactly what you need and has extensive documentation on how to create filters. If you want to filter because of security reasons, then by all means use it - it has a parser that can cope with the most crazy XSS schemes imaginable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :

```
strip_tags();
```

function in php.

**Sample Usage**:

```
    <?php
    $str = '<body>
            <div class="a"></div>
            <div id="b"><p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p></div>
            <div id="d"></div>
            </body>
           ';
    echo strip_tags($str);
    echo "\n";
    ?>
```

it will return :

```
Here are some text and HTML
```

**or**:

```
    <?php
     $str = '<body>
             <div class="a"></div>
             <div id="b"><p class="c">Here are some text and HTML</p></div>
             <div id="d"></div>
             </body>
            ';
     echo strip_tags($str, '<body>');
     echo "\n";
    ?>
```

this will allow '`<body>`' tag and will remve another tags.
result :

```
<body>
Here are some text and HTML
</body>
```

***More Examples***:[Php.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for. But thanks for your answer.